# How to validate an ASCII string with a two digit hexadecimal checksum appended?

Tags: embedded, checksum

I am using a Renesas 16 bt MCU with HEW (High-performance Embedded Workbench) compiler.

The system receives ACSII data of the form:

```
<data><cc>
```

where `<cc>` comprises two ASCII hex digits corresponding to the 8-bit bitwise XOR of all the preceding characters. The maximum length of the string including `<cc>` is 14.

Here is my attempt:

```
#pragma INTERRUPT Interrupt_Rx0
void Interrupt_Rx0 (void)
{
    unsigned char   rx_byte, rx_status_byte,hex;
    char buffer[15],test[5];
    int r,k[15];
    char * pEnd;
    unsigned char dat,arr[14],P3;
    unsigned int i,P1[10];

    rx_byte = u0rbl;    //get rx data
    rx_status_byte = u0rbh;

    if ((rx_status_byte & 0x80) == 0x00)        //if no error
    {
        if ((bf_rx0_start == 0) && (rx_byte == '?') && (bf_rx0_ready == 0))
        {


            byte_rx0_buffer[0]=rx_byte;
            bf_rx0_start = 1;                                    
            byte_rx0_ptr = 1;       
        }

        else
        {
            if (rx_byte == '?')
            {
                bf_rx0_start = 1;
                byte_rx0_ptr = 0;
            }
            if(bf_rx0_start == 1)
            {
                byte_rx0_buffer[byte_rx0_ptr++] = rx_byte;          

                sprintf(buffer,"%X",rx_byte); //ASCII CONVERSION
                dat=strtol(buffer,&pEnd,16);
                //  P1=(int)dat;
                //  sprintf(P1,"%s",dat);
                delay_ms(2000);
                k[byte_rx0_ptr++]=dat;  
            }                       

            if ((byte_rx0_ptr == 14))               
                bf_rx0_start = 0;//end further rx until detect new STX

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: They're already in ASCII. There's nothing you need to do.

Comment: Thanks for the reply .but the receiving command is in charaters only for eg ?01SRW68 for getting BCC for checking purpose I need to convert to hexadecimal value then only I can do the XOR operation for getting BCC in this case 68 is BCC value.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "hexadecimal value". Hexadecimal is a representation, only encodings (like ASCII) have values you can convert. (Say you have ten cars. If you converted that ten to hexadecimal, you still have precisely the same number of cars. So there's nothing to do.) Your question doesn't make any sense. You currently have "6" then "8" in ASCII. What do you want exactly?

Comment: I am getting "?01SRW68" from external device to the mcu,as per the external device (isaTouch Screen) manual for finding outa Block Check Value I need to perform XOR operation ie if this is the command then convert this value to hexadec value & xor it ie(3F^30^31^53^52^57=68), if i can do this calculation in program i can able to check if the bcc value is same to the receiving buffer on MCU,it these are same i can terminate the buffer and the receving buffer is ready for another commands.But the problem I am facing is mcu receving buffer can receive only one charater at a time .plz go thru code

Comment: See my update to my answer. You don't understand what it is you're trying to do. You *cannot* convert to hexadecimal and XOR because hexadecimal is a representation and you can only XOR values.

Comment: when i convert a character it is storing into an character array for eg (?-3f/arr[0]=3;arr[1]=f) i dont know how to combine these two. functions like atoi(),toascii() wont work in this compiler.

Comment: See my update to my answer.

Comment: that means if i do direct xor operation with these charaters then i will get the bcc value as 68.

Comment: You will get the *value* that is the XOR of those *values*, which is what you want so that you will have the correct *value* to send, compare, or whatever. Notice that you are operating entirely on *values*, it makes no difference how those values are represented.

Comment: The *value* of the *character* "6" *encoded* in ASCII is 36 when represented in hexadecimal and 54 when expressed in decimal. It is a vital programming skill to understand the difference between characters, values, encodings, and representations.

Comment: The question includes a lot of superfluous information and is hard to read.  Consider getting to the point and asking something more specific.  I suspect your compiler BTW is fully functional and ISO compliant - what makes you thing that a) it isn't and b) why it is relevant information in this question.

Comment: Never mind;  I cleaned it up.  You may want to check that it still asks what you intended.

Comment: Lack of atoi() or toascii() is not a deficiency in your compiler.  The compiler is distinct from the library, and you can always write your own library.  toascii() is not a standard library function.  atoi() is declared in `<stdlib.h>`; I'd be very surprised if it was not provided, however it is of no use in this case anyhow.

Comment: You have not been clear about what processor you are using (Renesas make several architectures) but the [documentation for the M16C compiler](http://documentation.renesas.com/doc/products/tool/doc/rej10j2188_nc30_u.pdf) for example suggests that a standard library (including `atoi()`) is provided.

Answer (score 2):

> convert this value to hexadec value & xor it ie(3F^30^31^53^52^57=68), if i can do this calculation in program

You fundamentally don't understand the difference between values and encodings. Two plus three is five whether you represent the two as "2", "two", or "X X". Addition operates on *values*, not representations. So to "convert to hexadecimal & xor it" makes no sense. You XOR **values**, not representations. Hexadecimal is a representation.

To maintain a running XOR, just do something like `int running_xor=0;` at the top and then  `running_xor ^= rx_byte;` each time you receive a byte. It will contain the correct value when you are finished. Set it to zero to reset it.

Get hexadecimal completely out of your head. That is just how those values are being printed for *your* consumption. That has nothing to do with the internal logic of your program which deals only in values.

Comment: I re-wrote the question for him in an attempt to avoid closure.  I may have changed the sense entirely, but it made little sense as it was!  This answer is a sterling effort at answering the question as it originally stood!+1  One problem however as I understand it is that it appears that the data length is variable, so until you get to the end of a message you cannot tell whether a character is part of the data or part of the checksum, so keeping a running XOR may be less practical than processing in a loop after reception is complete.

Answer (score 1):

You would do well to separate out the data validation from the data reception, even to the extent that you don't do it in the interrupt handler; it is likely to be better to buffer the data in the ISR unchecked and defer the data validation to the main code thread or a task-thread if you are using an RTOS.  You certainly don't want to be calling heavy-weight library functions such as sprintf() or strtol() in an ISR!

Either way, here is a function that would take a pointer to a received string, and its length (to avoid an unnecessary `strlen()` call since you already know how many characters were received), and returns `true` if the checksum validates, and `false` otherwise.  It has no restriction on data length - that would be performed by the calling function.

If you know that your checksum hex digits will always be either upper or lower-case, you can simplify the `decodeHexNibble()` function.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

uint8_t decodeHexNibble() ;
uint8_t decodeHexByte( char* hexbyte ) ;
uint8_t decodeHexNibble( char hexdigit ) ;

bool checkData( char* data, int length )
{
    int data_len = length - 2 ;
    char* bcc_ptr = &data[data_len] ;
    uint8_t rx_bcc_val = 0 ;
    uint8_t actual_bcc_val = 0 ;
    int i = 0 ;

    // Convert <cc> string to integer
    rx_bcc_val = decodeHexByte( bcc_ptr ) ;

    // Calculate XOR of <data>
    for( i = 0; i < data_len; i++ )
    {
        actual_bcc_val ^= data[i] ;
    }

    return actual_bcc_val == rx_bcc_val  ;
}

uint8_t decodeHexNibble( char hexdigit )
{
    uint8_t nibble ;

    if( hexdigit >= '0' && hexdigit <= '9' )
    {
        nibble = hexdigit - '0' ;
    }
    else if( hexdigit >= 'a' && hexdigit <= 'f' )
    {
        nibble = hexdigit - 'a' + 10 ;
    }
    else if( hexdigit >= 'A' && hexdigit <= 'F' )
    {
        nibble = hexdigit - 'A' + 10 ;
    }
    else
    {
        // Do something 'sensible' with invalid digits
        nibble = 0 ;
    }

    return nibble ;
}

uint8_t decodeHexByte( char* hexbyte )
{
    uint8_t byte = hexbyte[0] << 4 ;
    byte |= hexbyte[1] ;

    return byte ;
}
```

Comment: Sir,Thanks for spending a little time for me.I hope you understood what's my issue.In my program when a string or command  have length of 14 then program works perfectly,when the command size is less than 14 ie the string coming from external device (touch screen) is overwriting the previous string in the receiving buffer,then the commands gets corrupted,so for resolving this issue I planned for comparing the BCC value.If the calculated BCC value is equal to the value present in buffer then bf_rx0_start = 0;.If condition is yes then rx buffer is ready for next command.

Comment: Your real problem is one of avoiding the corruption, not checking for it after the event!  I think you need to start again with the question and clearly specify the protocol being used by teh touchescreen.

Comment: From your original example, it looks like the device is using uses a message format "?<addr><cmd><text><checksum><cr>".  I am guessing - you really need ot clearly specify - edit the question again to be clear.  Any how, if this is the case you need to use the <cr> (carriage return or '\r') to detect the end of a message and process it - assuming a fixed length of 14 is not going to work.  You would probably do better to simply have your ISR place characters into a ring buffer and have the main thread process messages.

Comment: Sir the format is like this for eg ?01SRR0001016D 
 Header(?) Destination(01) Command(SRR) Destination(0001) Data(01) BCC(6D)ie XOR of all other variable.Here the problem is when the command become BDW then the array size should change to 16.Similarly SRW then the array size will be 8. For that what changes I made in the code.

Comment: No, you are really missing the point.  You need to edit your question *yourself* to include this information, you should at least specify the device manufacturer and product that you are using so that anyone can get the documentation, or you might link directly to the documentation.  Adding this information in comments is *not appropriate*. I found what appears to be the same protocol in a Aromat GT-10 touchscreen manual, and every message is terminated by <cr> - that is how you determine the end of the message and its length.

Comment: Sir,Thanks a lot for helping me,I am using Panasonic GT-02,now i got a solution for my issue.I am expecting your help for my future, I am beginner in Embedded field.

Comment: Sir,I have a mcu code for I/O operation,so that I can able to connect 10 outputs & 10 inputs.In that code the programmer is used to decleare & defined data using extern union & also in the program  if condition is there,but he is not defined any values to that variables,then how these variables will get values,here i attached a few part of the code.extern union byte_def byte_flag_8;   #define bf_state_on_sensor1 byte_flag_8.bit.b1      if (!bf_state_on_sensor1)      like this he is mentioned in the program I dont know this variable is getting value & what is use of extern union.

Comment: @user1536788: StackOverflow is not used like a traditional forum; it is a strict Q&A format, not a conversation thread - you should not extend your question in teh comments section, that is for discussion of the specific answer to question to which it is attached.  It seems that you are in fact asking an entirely new question, so post a new one.